# GTK3 Python type in dropdown box

Tags: python, gtk3

Is there away that I can make drop down box accept text. As I want to make the drop down box list previous item typed and be able to add new items.

I have had a good search on google but not found anything.

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are looking for a `Gtk.ComboBoxText` with entry.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
combo_box = Gtk.ComboBoxText.new_with_entry()
```

See [here for the documentation](http://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkComboBoxText.html)